# Stopping a service in c++ when do I use the ExitProcess() func

Tags: c++, service

I'm stopping a service in my application wanted to know what is the usage of 
ExitProcess and if I should use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never need to use `ExitProcess()` to stop a service. In fact, you should never need to use `ExitProcess()` at all.

Services are deeply intertwined with the SCM, and if a service that it thinks should be running just vanishes it will take some action to repair it. In extreme cases, it will force the system to reboot.

The correct way to stop a service is to use the documented API to ask the SCM to ask the service to stop. It often takes several seconds for this process to complete as the service itself usually needs to a clean shutdown after asking its worker threads to finish up and halt.

The privileges required to interact with the SCM are less dangerous than that required to end an arbitrary process, but neither is usually granted outside of the Administrators group.

**Edit:** A comment asked about stopping a service from inside itself.

That can be a tough call, especially if the service is in some kind of unfortunate state. The service and the SCM absolutely have to agree that the service is stopping, or the SCM will take the recovery action that was configured for the service.

I do have a complete implementation of a service that might serve as an alternative point of view for how to handle some of these things. It is [LuaService](http://luaforge.net/projects/luaservice/) and is a framework that allows a (single worker thread) service to be implemented in pure [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) aside from the LuaService executable itself. Its [reference manual](http://luaforge.net/docman/view.php/326/1640/LuaService.pdf) attempts to fully document the internals, as well as document some of the details of a service's lifetime that are otherwise documented through the interaction of various articles on MSDN.

Comment: What do you suggest for stopping  the service from within the service (when needed)?
I am using CONTROL_SERVICE( with SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP but I want to stop it evem if it is stuck in stoppping...

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. I'm not certain I've addressed your specific issue, but I'm also not certain it can be addressed in any case.

Comment: This answer is not correct. There may be cases where ExitProcess() makes sense. See my answer.

Comment: ["If you are creating services that share a process, avoid calling functions with process-wide effects, such as ExitProcess. In addition, do not unload your service DLL."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Look into the *[OpenSCManager()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684323(VS.85).aspx)*, *[OpenService()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330(VS.85).aspx)* and *[ControlService()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330(VS.85).aspx)* Windows API calls. Note that your program may not have the necessary permissions to call these, so elevation may be necessary - see [Service Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981(VS.85).aspx) for further information.

There is also an example [how to stop a service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686335(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: This ends a service from another application. But your answer does not tell how a service can stop itself. (See my answer)

Answer (score 2):

I see that none of the posts here really answers the original question.

RBerteig wrote: *"In extreme cases, it will force the system to reboot."*

This is nonsense. This might happen if you kill WinLogon.exe, but is not valid for services in general.

If you stop a service from another application you will obviously use

```
ControlService(mh_Service, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &k_Status);
```

But what if a service decides that it's work is done and it wants to shut down itself?

The correct way is this (if your service does not run in a shared process):

```
void cService::Suicide()
{
    // Inform the Service Control Manager that the service is stopped now.
    SERVICE_STATUS k_Status = {0};
    k_Status.dwServiceType      = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS; 
    k_Status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    k_Status.dwCurrentState     = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    SetServiceStatus(mh_Service, &k_Status);

    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

I use this code in my service class and it works perfectly on any version of Windows from XP to Windows 10.

!Obviously you should do any **cleanup work** that is required before calling this function!

Comment: One reason not to use `ExitProcess()` is if the service is sharing a process with other services. If it is, then `ExitProcess()` will take all the other services with it without informing the SCM. Since it is the service's installer that recommends whether the service should reside in a private process or can share a process with others, the service itself may not be aware of that situation. Certainly, your `Suicide()` method here does not worry about that and can take out other services. If some of those are critical, bad things can follow.

Comment: You are completely right. This will not work for shared services that run svchost.exe. But my service is a SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  where this will cause no problem.

Comment: Not all services are built that way. Hence the general advice which is safe for all kinds of services.

Comment: My answer applies only for stand alone services. I add some notes to your comments:
1.) An installer always knows if a service runs as own process or as shared process because the installation is different. A standalone service is an EXE while a shared service is a DLL. 2.) It is not recommended and not documented by Microsoft to write shared services to run in svchost because if they crash, they will pull down the half of Windows' services. See first answer in http://forum.sysinternals.com/writing-a-service-that-runs-under-svchost_topic11974.html

Comment: exactly ! for stopping a service with another programs, we should just send `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` and the service control handler will get this signal and stops the service. But in the service itself , the control handler will stop the service. Am I right ?

Comment: @ Mohammadreza: It seems you did not understand my answer. Please read it again. In my sample code above it is NOT the control handler which stops the service. It is ExitProcess()

Answer (score 0):

ExitProcess is for ending the process itself (much like ExitThread ends a thread).  This is used to end a process (program or DLL), though Microsoft don't recommend it for ending a DLL.

If you are trying to stop yourself (you are the process), you can use ExisProcess, though I would recommend a cleaner shutdown, to make sure everything is cleanly stopped.  ExitProcess, like ExitThread, stops without unwinding the stack, so no destructors are called.

From within a service, you stop based on an external signal.  You could respond to that by calling ExitProcess, but it would probably be better to have some form of shutdown that closes anything necessary and logs this.